# Dell D620 can't detect external monitor when docked

Tags: 12.04, nvidia, dell, external-monitor

Installing 12.04 on Dell D620 laptop (Nvidia Quadro NVS 110M) in a Dell docking station  with Dell 1907FP external monitor. During install the external monitor is used fine but once installed, the 12.04 'Monitor' utility steadfastly refuses to detect anything external and I have to use the laptop screen for everything.

Lots of external monitor questions but I cannot find the golden key to unlock this frustrating behaviour which is a step backwards from 11.04 (using to make this post) which happily detects the Dell monitor.

The external drivers utility reports I am using the latest version of Nvidia graphics drivers and it is activated and in use.

Comment: Are you using nouveau driver? If yes, try install nvidia-current to use the proprietary driver. In most case I found nvidia-current has more reliable support for multiple monitors.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried activating the monitor through the Nvidia X-Server Settings? I couldn't change the resolution through 'Displays', but once I turned on the monitor through the Nvidia control panel, my external monitor started working.

I am using the Nvidia NVS 3100M with a Lenovo Thinkpad T510.